# histogram improving performances in cuda

Tags: histogram

I'm a student and working on a projet on image processing
and i'm testing some cuda code performances.

I've tested the histogram computation available in the
Nvidia samples (my computer is a GeFROCE 720M) but i'm 
having very poor performances.
In the book "CUDA by example" it's said that performances 
are poor when atomic operations are used but it can be
 improved by using shared memory (which make the code to be 
faster than the CPU).

But when i look at the sample's code shared memory is beeing used
and i don't understand why i still such poor performance (slower 
than the CPU).

i'm surely getting something wrong and i'm wondering on what can be done
to improve the performances.

Comment: Have you tried running it under `nvvp` (nvidia visual profiler) or `nvprof` (command-line profiler)? `nvvp`, in particular, can give you hints about what might be wrong and there are tutorials on how to use it. They're both in the CUDA SDK.

Comment: indeed when i run it under _nvcc_ it's faster. I'm now trying to look at what can be the reason. But yet still even the performance obtained under _nvcc_ is still slower (but close) than the CPU performance. And even in some forums i read that Histogramming is not particularly efficient when implemented with CUDA unless the input image is very very large.